# Java Class Files not recognized by ls or ls -a

Tags: java, javac

After I successfully compile both java files using " javac -d /mypath/classes -s /mypath/source filename.java" I run the Main file from the source directory using " java -classpath -d /mypath/classes Main "
The terminal will successfully output as follows:

```
Make: Mazda
Color: White
Year: 1997
Model: Miata MX-5
```

When I ls either the classes directory or source directory I get nothing. I try ls -l and I total 0 in both directories. I tried ls -a and the terminal tells me " . .. " I think that signifies there are two files in there, but I cant see them at all. How do I make it so I can see the created class files and source files that I compiled with `javac`?

```
#Car.java 
public class Car {
    String model;
    String make;
    String color;
    int year;

    public void getCarFacts(){
        System.out.println("Model: " + model);
        System.out.println("Make: " + make);
        System.out.println("Color: " + color);
        System.out.println("Year: " + year);
    }
}

#Main.java
public class Main{
    public static void(String args[]){
        Car myCar
        myCar = new Car();
        myCar.model = "Miata MX-5";
        myCar.make = "Mazda";
        myCar.color = "White";
        myCar.year = 1997;

        myCar.getCarFacts();
    }
}
# ===File Tree===
├── classes
├── source
└── workspace
    ├── Car.java
    └── Main.java
```

Entire terminal output from start to finish

```
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1$ tree ./
./
├── classes
├── source
└── workspace
    ├── Car.java
    └── Main.java

3 directories, 2 files
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1$ cd workspace
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1/workspace$ javac -d /hope/proj1/classes -s /hope/proj1/source Car.java
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1/workspace$ javac -d /hope/proj1/classes -s /hope/proj1/source Main.java
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1/workspace$ cd ..
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1$ cd source
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1/source$ java -classpath /hope/proj1/classes Main
Make: Mazda
Color: White
Year: 1997
Model: Miata MX-5
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1/source$ cd ..
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1$ cd source
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1/source$ ls -a
.  ..
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1/source$ ls -l
total 0
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1/source$ ls
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1/source$ cd ..
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1$ cd classes
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1/classes$ ls -a
.  ..
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1/classes$ ls -l
total 0
achrotz@penguin:~/hope/proj1/classes$ ls
```

Comment: Please share the screenshot of the directory structure and the terminal output as well. Do make sure that you are performing the commands against the same directory in both the cases.

Comment: Thank you nullpointer, I am new to stack overflow and had trouble formatting the question.

Comment: *"I run ... using 'java -classpath -d /mypath/classes Main.java'"* No you don't. You run without the `.java` extension. --- Also, that code doesn't compile.

Comment: Just noticed that the output you've shared doesn't match the class shared by you as well. Do make sure that the content provided here is sane enough in terms of someone trying to verify it.

Comment: **I tried ls -a and the terminal tells me " . .. "** - . and .. are not files but directory paths. `.` is the current directory and `..` is the current directory's parent. These are a red herring for you.

Comment: Since your two source files are in `workspace`, why do you believe `ls` of `source` should show them? Did you try `ls` of the `workspace` directory?

Comment: I specified to save the source files in /source and class files in /classes. And {ls} of workspace only shows me Main.java and Car.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one directory structure at root level `/hope/proj1/...` where your source files and classes are then you have the same structure in your home directory that is empty and where you perform your `ls`, `~/hope/proj1 /...`

This will compile the Car.java file found outside of your home folder

```
javac -d /hope/proj1/classes -s /hope/proj1/source Car.java
```

This will compile the Car.java file found inside of your home folder and store the class file inside the home folder as well

```
javac -d ~/hope/proj1/classes -s ~/hope/proj1/source Car.java
```

but since you seem to have the source files in the workspace folder the above would have to be changed to

```
javac -d ~/hope/proj1/classes -s ~/hope/proj1/workspace Car.java
```

Comment: could you clarify for me, I'm not to sure what you are saying

Comment: /hope means a folder at the top of your directory structure on the disk while ~/hope means a folder in your home directory. Do `ls -al /` and you should see a `hope´ folder there among other stuff and then do 'ls -al ~/` and you should also have a folder `hope` together with the files and folder in your home folder.

Comment: When performing both of those commands, I do see the hope directory with other stuff. However I do not see the compiled Car.class and Main.class. Also thank you for being patient with me

Comment: Well not on the top level of course, this was just to help you understand the difference between the two, you still have to dig down like you have done before. `ls -al /hope/proj1/classes` or `cd /hope/proj1` followed by `ls -al classes/` for instance